# how do i return this instance of the IInfocard interface?

Tags: c#, class, interface

i am currently trying to return a instance of the Iinforcard interface within my "createNewInfocard" function, however i keep running into error CS0266. i am unsure as to how fix this.

```
public interface IInfoCard
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Category { get; }
        string GetDataAsString();
        void DisplayData(Panel displayPanel);
        void CloseDisplay();
        bool EditData();
    }




public interface IInfoCardFactory
{
    IInfoCard CreateNewInfoCard(string category);
    IInfoCard CreateInfoCard(string initialDetails);
    string[] CategoriesSupported { get; }
    string GetDescription(string category);
}

 public class Class1 : IInfoCardFactory
    {

    public IInfoCard CreateNewInfoCard(string category)
    {

        Class1 x;
        x = new Class1();
        return x;// i keep at getting error CS0266 at this return statement.
    }


}
```

Comment: Class1 does not implement IInfoCard! the error you are getting should make sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

`Class1` *must implement* `IInfoCard` interface, i.e.

```
  public class Class1 : 
     IInfoCardFactory, 
     IInfoCard  // <- notice IInfoCard implementation
  {
     public IInfoCard CreateNewInfoCard(string category)
     {
        Class1 x;
        x = new Class1();
        return x;// i keep at getting error CS0266 at this return statement.
     }
     ...
     //TODO: put here IInfoCard methods and properties implementations
  }
```

now, in your current code, `Class1` implements `IInfoCardFactory` but not `IInfoCard`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a class that implements your `IInfoCard` interface?

An interface on its own is just going to define some functionality that a class should have, so you need a concrete implementation in order to use it :

```
// Notice the IInfoCard declaration, indicating Class1 implements it
public class Class1 : IInfoCardFactory, IInfocard
{
     /* Omitted for brevity */
}
```

This should allow you to return your `Class1` object from your `CreateNewInfoCard()` method as it will now qualify as an `IInfoCard` object since it implements it.